# Why is Promise.all(..) passing unresolved/pending promises in attached then handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from 2 APIs in parallel using the `fetch` API and `Promise.all` functionality. Expectedly when all the promises in the given array are resolved the callback in `then` is executed. But I am getting pending promises in the callback function.

The function code is used to achieve the required goal

```
const fun = () => {
  const fetchPromises = [
    fetch('api-1'),
    fetch('api-2')
  ];

  Promise.all(fetchPromises)
    .then( responses => responses.map( res => res.json()))
    .then(result => {
      console.dir(result);
      // do something with results
    });
}
```

I expect the callback function of `then` to be executed only when Promise.all is resolved, and Promise.all is resolved only when all of the promised in the given array are resolved as well. So in the callback function of the second `then` should have resulted as an array of responses from the APIs.

However, the result I am getting in the console is this:

```
result
(2) [Promise, Promise]
  0: Promise
    [[PromiseStatus]]: "pending",
    [[PromiseValue]]: undefined
    __proto__: Promise
  1: Promise {<pending>}
  length: 2
```

i.e the unresolved/pending promises are passed to be callback.

I guess I may be missing a vital point here regarding `Promise.all` functionality. What is the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.json` returns a Promise too, so `responses.map( res => res.json())` is returning an array of Promise that you need to wait for

You need to use `Promise.all` around `responses.map( res => res.json())` too

```
Promise.all(fetchPromises)
    .then( responses => Promise.all(responses.map( res => res.json())))
    .then(result => {
      console.dir(result);
      // do something with results
    });
```

Comment: So is this pattern ok for making 2(or more) API calls using `fetch`. It seems quite unintuitive using `Promise.all` twice that too in callbacks.

Comment: Using `fetch` you have to do that. Personally, I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) which has a nice Promise based API